# How to install pip install pycairo? getting error

Tags: ubuntu, pip

when I'm Try to install the Pycario im getting this error please help me to solve this error. Im using Ubuntu 20

```
$ /workspace/development/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /workspace/development/frappe-bench/apps/erpnext_uyn_customizations 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      running build_ext
      Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'cairo' found
      Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
ERROR: 
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/workspace/development/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /workspace/development/frappe-bench/apps/erpnext_uyn_customizations ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I try to get my frappe `custom_app`. when I try to pull the app im getting this error please help me how to sort

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+No+package+cairo+found

Answer (score 3):

You need `cairo` to build `pycairo`, see [the docs]. To install `cairo` and its headers, run

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
```